# Problems installing PHP EzComponents using pyrus

Tags: php, pear, wamp, pyrus

It seems that the Ez Components repository will not play nice with pyrus. It seems to 302 when pyrus tries to download the package. Has anyone had any luck installing this? It's a requirement for PHPUnit.

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5>php pyrus.phar install  ezc/eZComponents
Pyrus version 2.0.0a3 SHA-1: BE7EA9D171AE3873F1BBAF692EEE9165BB14BD5D
Using PEAR installation found at pyrus
Downloading components.ez.no/eZComponents

PEAR2\Pyrus\Package\Exception: Invalid abstract package components.ez.no/eZCompo
nents
 PEAR2\Pyrus\Package\Exception: Could not download from "http://components.ez.no
/get/eZComponents-2009.2.1.phar"
  PEAR2\Pyrus\Package\Exception: Download failed, received 302
```

Comment: Please report that problem as a bug in the pyrus bugtracker on github.

Answer (score 3):

`302` is the status code for `FOUND` (meaning: Hey, look at `Location` where to find what you are looking for). Usually a client should follow the link given in the `Location`-header, but it seems, that Pyrus doesn't. This should be treated as a bug (as mentioned by cweiske).

Answer (score 2):

This is not the only problem. ezComponents Location header redirects to /. So I don't think fixing this bug alone will help. It seems ezComponents has quite a weird setup that pyrus can't deal with.

Pyrus works fine with phpunit.de and so on.

Comment: I think you may be right. In the end I used a newer version of PEAR to install phpunit2. I am no longer working with this machine so I can't really help test it out.